# Opening popup box on the basis of selected radio button in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, prototypejs

I have 2 radio buttons of same group.

If I hit on search I want to open popup box.

**Condition:**

When first radio button is selected new popup box come.

When second radio button is selected new popup box come which is different from first popup. I have created code, but it is not working.

```js
function mysearch() {


  var par = new Array();
  var form = $('mytestForm');
  var y = form.getInputs('radio', 'radioId');
  if ($('radioId1234').checked == true || $('radioId5678').checked == true) {
   
    wmGlobalObj.remErrAdvice();
    par[0] = $F(y.find(function(re) {
      return re.checked;
    }));
    if (paras[0] == '1234') 
      

      window.open('https://www.google.co.in/', 'FirstSearch', 'width=460,height=250', 'testsrch');
    else if (par[0] == "5678") 
      window.open('http://www.bing.com/', 'SecondSearch', 'width=460,height=50', 'testsrch');
    }
  } else {
    alert("error")
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.2/prototype.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" id="mytestForm" name="mytestForm">
  <label for="radioId"></label>
  <input type="radio" name="radioId">
  <label class="styled" for="radioId1234">Search when First radio button is selected</label>
  <input type="radio" class="styled" name="radioId">
  <label class="styled" for="radioId567">Search when second radio button is selected</label>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <a title="Lookup" id="testmine" href="mysearch()">search</a> 
</form>
```

Comment: *"but it is not working"* - What does that mean? Nothing happens, or the wrong thing happens? Do you get errors in your browser's console? Is the problem perhaps that sometimes you use a variable `par` and sometimes `paras`? Why is `par` an array when you only ever use the first element?

Comment: You updated one of them. But didn't add an explanation of what is going wrong...

Comment: @nnnnnn: I am getting error as: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getInputs' of null"

Comment: What's `$`? Does it refer to jQuery, or prototype? Your question is tagged with both...

Comment: @nnnnnn: no prototypejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably can do this alot simpler by just using CSS selectors.

For example

```
var checked_inputs = $$('form#mytestForm input[type="radio"]:checked');

if(checked_inputs.length > 0)
{
       if(checked_inputs[0].value == "1234")
       {
           window.open('https://www.google.co.in/', 'FirstSearch', 'width=460,height=250', 'testsrch');
           //this exits the foreach loop
       }
       else if(checked_inputs[0].value == "5678")
       {
           window.open('http://www.bing.com/', 'SecondSearch', 'width=460,height=50', 'testsrch');
       }
}
else
{
    alert('error');
}
```

Comment: +1, I  tried your idea but it is not working and even not give error in console. http://jsfiddle.net/Mikephils/1pd8mzvc/

Comment: I fixed it by using an event observer http://jsfiddle.net/1pd8mzvc/3/ --whoops it looks like you pulled the library in using the external load - you can just use the dropdown to load the prototype lib